# ubuntu/bash sed: operation not permitted and permission denied

Tags: bash, permissions, sed

I'm using Windows 10 with WSL2 feature turned on, and working on Ubuntu. All the files I'm working with are saved in Windows and not the Ubuntu subsystem, so I've been accessing Windows directories (`/mnt/c/Users/username/...`) whenever I needed the files.

I'm running a shell script on Ubuntu and a line with `sed` comment keeps on giving me errors. I've tried a number of things I found online but none of them are working for me now.
The line I'm having trouble is `sed -i -e 's/ 100 bp//' file.fasta`.  `file.fasta` contains hundreds of lines of text, and some of those lines have `bp` tags at the end so I'm trying to remove those tags.

The line above gives me the following error:

```
sed: preserving permissions for './sedxlnBcv': Operation not permitted
sed: cannot rename ./sedxlnBcv: Permission denied
```

I tried running `chmod +w .` to give the current directory permission for writing, then it gave me this error:

```
chmod: changing permissions of '.': Operation not permitted
```

(This was confusing because I was able to create a text file in the current directory using `cat>filename.txt` and I thought that meant I have write access to the directory?)

But anyway I moved up a directory by `cd ..` and tried `chmod -R a+X`, which still returned the same error:

```
chmod: changing permissions of 'file_in_directory': Operation not permitted
```

Then I tried creating a new file without the `100 bp` tags and tried to overwrite the new file into the old file like below, which gave me a different error:

```
$ sed -i -e 's/ 100 bp//' file.fasta > newfile.fasta; mv newfile.fasta file.fasta
sed: preserving permissions for '.sedg8L00D': Operation not permitted
sed: cannot rename ./sedg8L00D: Permission denied
mv: replace 'file.fasta', overriding mode 0555 (r-xr-xr-x)?
```

Then I tried copying `file.fasta` into a directory I can work in and moving it back out but it also gave a different error. (The top three lines are what I put in the shell script but the error is coming from executing the first line):

```
$ cp file.fasta /tmp
$ sed -i -e 's/ 100 bp//' /tmp/file.fasta
$ cat /tmp/file.fasta > ~/newfile.fasta
cp: cannnot create regular file '/tmp/file.fasta': Permission denied
```

I'm running out of ideas on what to do... Can anyone give me some suggestions or point out what mistakes I'm making?

Comment: Since you are working on the Windows filesystem with Windows the permission system, I suggest using Windows tools to modify them - see this related question on [so]: [permission denied when sed in place edit in mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313318/permission-denied-when-sed-in-place-edit-in-mingw)

Comment: @steeldriver When I go to Security tab and check my permissions, I already have Full control and all the other items checked "Allow" (the checks are greyed out too).